# Why is the angular material modal transparent?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have an angular material modal:

```
process(assignmentNumber) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = { assignmentNumber }
    this.dialog.open(ProcessPostReleaseExceptionComponent, dialogConfig);

}
```

When the modal is accessed it is completely transparent:

[image: transparent modal]

I cannot find a setting in the documentation that shows how to change this. Is there some step missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular modal will just serve you an overlay. In your ProcessPostReleaseExceptionComponent, just put a `<div>` with a `background-color`.